# How to alias rm to always confirm

Tags: bash, rm, alias

When I use the command `rm -rf`, I want to make sure a prompt always appears before deleting a file, so I tried adding this to `~/.bashrc`

```
alias 'rm -rf'='rm -rfi'
```

But it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: I believe it is a bad idea to alias existing standard POSIX commands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Confirmation is a weak way to achieve the result you want: not deleting files you didn't want to delete. I can ask you to confirm 10 times in a row, but if since you just asked me to delete `mispeled.txt` you will not realize your error until after you confirmed it.

Better to use `trash` or similar command on your system that sends files to the (recoverable) "recycle-bin". There is an RPM build of the `trash-cli` package at [rpmfind.net](ftp://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/dag/redhat/el6/i386/trash-cli-0.11.2-1.el6.rf.i686.html) but I can't vouch for that version. When in doubt build it yourself [from the source code](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli).

As noted in the comments it is a bad idea to alias `rm` at all, because it *will* come back to bite you when you are in a shell that has no protective alias and your brain is accustomed to having a "safe" `rm`.

Comment: Aliasing rm is a horrible idea for reasons stated here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17622/how-can-i-make-rm-move-files-to-the-trash-can

Comment: @rouble Search for package `trash-cli` that provides a `/bin/trash`.

Comment: but there is no trash-cli on Centos7 @BinaryZebra

Comment: @LawrenceLi it was an attempt to make sense of what msw wrote.

Answer (score 6):

In your `~/.bashrc`, you can just do this instead:

```sh
alias rm='rm -i'
```

This way, when you type `rm -rf example-dir`, Bash translates it to `rm -i -rf example-dir`.

Note that for interactive login shells, `~/.bash_profile` is used instead. To make login shells also use `~/.bashrc`, simply add this to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```sh
[ -f ~/.bashrc ] && . ~/.bashrc
```

Now `~/.bashrc` will always execute any time you open a terminal or ssh session.

Answer (score 2):

f --> force, never prompt

i --> prompt every time

If you need to be prompted, just use `rm -i` in the alias. You could have 2 aliases (rmf and rmi) if you wish to have both.

Comment: But `-i` takes precedence over `-f`, so `rm -rf -i` will still ask for confirmation.

Comment: @Will The modifier that appears later takes precedent. so `rm -f -i` will prompt, but `rm -i -f` will not prompt.

Comment: Not on my system.

Comment: @Will: Using `rm` on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6: "The -f option overrides any previous -i options." Seeing as there are different implementations of this program, I'd advise against aliasing `rm` at all.

Answer (score 1):

`rm -rfi` would give you the prompt, however `rm -i -rf` would not. 
Your alias make your commands to the latter one.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to valid answers, I would advise you to separate your aliases into `~/.bash_aliases`, and source it simpy in the end of `~/.bashrc`

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

As has been already said, your alias is twisted into mutually exclusive options:

> ```
> ‘-f’
>  ‘--force’
>  Ignore nonexistent files and missing operands, and never prompt the
>  user.  Ignore any previous ‘--interactive’ (‘-i’) option.
> ```

^ taken from `info rm`.

Thus, the following would work:

```
alias rm='\rm -i'
```